# How to use @TexboxFor() along with @IEnumerable<>()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a small application and I want to add `AjaxForm` on Index view.
Index Page contains all the Products details and i want to add "Create New Product Form" on the same page at the bottom of the page ? but here is a little bit issue?

On the Top of the Page i have included `@model IEnumerable<ShoppingCart.Models.Product>`

On the Form section i can't use html Helpers such as `TextboxFor`, `DropdownBoxFor` etc..

How to Use `HtmlHelper` along with `IEnumerable`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use it? Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: I used normal html for that... @HoomanBahreini

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do? What does you Model (Product) look like? Do you want to iterate the IEnumerable and display your model for each iteration? Which field of your model do you want to show?

Comment: No... I want to use AjaxForm right after All products list...Please review the question once more... . .